# U(n) v.s. SO(n) and their quotient / homogeneous spaces

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups, lie-algebras, quotient-spaces, homogeneous-spaces

By counting the number of generators, it is easy to see that unitary group U(n) has much more generator than SO(n).

1. So it would make sense to consider the mod out group or the quotient space of U(n)/SO(n).

   - What is the quotient space U(10)/SO(10)?
   - What is the quotient space U(16)/SO(16)?
2. On the other hand, we can consider possibly 
   $$
   1 \to N \to \text{U}(n) \to  \text{SO}(n)\to 1,
   $$
   such that $N$ is some proper normal subgroup of a topological group, such that

   - $
     \text{U}(10) /N=\text{SO}(10)=?
     $
   - $
     \text{U}(16) /N=\text{SO}(16)=?
     $

What are the $N$ group/space?

You may get my questions but find my descriptions imprecise, so please help on answering and clarifying the question to an appropriate manner.

Comment: $SO(n)$ is not a normal subgroup of $U(n)$.

Comment: It does not need to be normal, one can consider simply the homogeneous space or quotient space.

Comment: Also I am not asking the specific general, I am saying $n=10,16$.

Comment: Also note that U(2)/SO(2)=U(2)/U(1)=PSU(2)-SO(3), so for some n, it makes sense to have a quotient

Comment: But for the "specific general", $n=10,16$ the same is true what Lord Shark says. The question is not clear in part 1 "What is the group $U(10)/SO(10)$"? Answer: It is not a group.

Comment: changed to quotient space

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by “what is the quotient space U(10)/SO(10)”? That is, what kind of description are you looking for that would be more satisfactory than “it is U(10)/SO(10)”?

Comment: more precise descriptions of manifolds and the space

Comment: U(10)/SO(10) seems like a very precise description of a 55-dimensional manifold. If you want a general interpretation of what U(n)/SO(n) is, maybe the section “geometric models of loop spaces” at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bott_periodicity_theorem could help (though since you are restricting specifically to n=10,16 I am not sure this is what you are looking for). Otherwise, perhaps you could clarify what you mean by “precise”.